# php xpath how to get values from multiple elements inside a parent element

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I need to gather all this data from a specific site. I need the URL, Image, Text. Here is the code I am trying to use. But I need to gather all the pieces of info from all the  tags on the page.

```
<article>
    <a href="http://www.link.com">
      <div><img src="https://image.com/image.png" /></div>
      <div>History</div>
      <div><h3>Content Here.</h3></div>
</article>
<article>
    <a href="http://www.link.com">
      <div><img src="https://image.com/image.png" /></div>
      <div>History</div>
      <div><h3>Content Here.</h3></div>
</article>
<article>
    <a href="http://www.link.com">
      <div><img src="https://image.com/image.png" /></div>
      <div>History</div>
      <div><h3>Content Here.</h3></div>
</article>
```

php code

```
$html = file_get_contents($feed_url);
        $dom = new DOMDocument();
        @$dom->loadHTML($html);
        $xpath = new DomXPath($dom);
        $articles = $xpath->query("//article");
        $items = array();

        foreach($articles as $article) {
                $link = $xpath->query("//a/@href", $article);
                $img = $xpath->query("//img/@src", $article);
                $link = $xpath->query("//h3", $article);
        }
```

I can't seem to get this to return any values. I can get a single value through the foreach. But I need all the others as well. I can't quite figure out how to make this happen. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I change your `foreach` loop like this:

```
foreach($articles as $article) {
        $link = $xpath->query(".//a/@href", $article);
        $img = $xpath->query(".//img/@src", $article);
        $head = $xpath->query(".//h3", $article);
        echo $link[0]->nodeValue . "  ". $img[0]->nodeValue  . "  ". $head[0]->nodeValue . "\n";
}
```

I get this as output (I added numbers to the elements just to distinguish the tree `<article>` nodes:

```
http://www.link1.com  https://image.com/image1.png  Content1 Here.
http://www.link2.com  https://image.com/image2.png  Content2 Here.
http://www.link3.com  https://image.com/image3.png  Content3 Here.
```

Is that what you're looking for?